# Dagger how to inject multiple constructors

Tags: android, dependency-injection, mvp, dagger

For example:

```
class A{
  B b;
  C c;
  @Inject
  A(B b){
    this.b = b;
  }
  @Inject
  A(C c){
    this.c = c;
  }
}
```

And in one of the module:

```
@Module
public class BModule {

private final B b;
public BModule(B b){
    this.b = b;
}

@Provides
BInterface provideB(){
    return b;
}
}
```

But I got error that I can't inject two constructors in a class, what should I do to handle the problem? Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Classes are only ever constructed once; two constructors would never both be called on the same instance, so having two constructors annotated @Inject means that Dagger would have to pick one. *What behavior are you trying to accomplish with those two annotated constructors?*

Ideally, combine the constructors.

```
@Inject
A(B b, C c){
  this.b = b;
  this.c = c;
}
```

Or switch one to [method injection](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39400989/1426891) if absolutely necessary:

```
@Inject
A(B b){
  this.b = b;
}
@Inject
void initialize(C c){ // Dagger calls this automatically
  this.c = c;
}
```

Comment: my real problem is, I try to build Presenter with the instance of View and Model, however, since, Model can't be initialized without View itself. So it's more like a paradox. Finally I give up and only implement dagger between Presenter and View. Please inform me if you have better solution to this practice, thank you!

Comment: Ah, yes, that requires a very different answer than the question you appeared to ask above. Bear in mind that you'd have equal trouble constructing this type of circular dependency by hand! Dagger added a feature that helps, though: You can [_inject a `Provider<B>` or `Provider<C>` instead_](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/dagger-discuss/KRDGFD3rUGQ) with no additional bindings or configuration needed (per the ["Bindings in the graph" section of the Dagger 2 User's Guide](https://google.github.io/dagger/users-guide.html#bindings-in-the-graph)).